# Why can template parameters not be deduced from array sizes in function parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

I have have the following code using templates and array dimension as template non-type parameter

```
template<int n> double f(double c[n]);
...
double c[5];
f<5>(c);  // compiles
f(c);  // does not compile
```

should not the compiler to be able to instantiate the second f without explicit template parameter? I am using g++4.1

Comment: MSVC will let you get away with murder.

Comment: VC8 won't - at least not with sane settings :)

Comment: I was mistaken. MSVC lets you do double (&c)[n] which is obviously, not the same thing. Comeau is also cool with double (&c)[n]. Amazing the difference a few parens will make.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It works when using references:

```
template<size_t n> double f(double (&c)[n]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, because when you pass `double c[5]` to f(), or any array to any function which takes an array for that matter, you lose the size information.  You are only passing a pointer.

**Edit:** But see gf's answer for a workaround.

Comment: Your comment, whilst correct, is unrelated. True, at runtime there is no way to determine the size of an array, but template parameter deduction occurs at compile-time. The compiler knows that the size of the array is 5 and can deduce the template parameter accordingly, though there are some limitations on that.

Comment: There's no way at runtime to determine the original declared type of *any* primitive. You do lose information when you pass it to a function that expects a pointer, but you lose it in the same way that you lose information when you pass a float to a function that expects an integer. To be more specific, the type of the array at declaration time is "array of 5 doubles", or double [5]. The sized array type has an implicit cast to a pointer. This cast is so common that we tend to forget it isn't the original type of the array, but it's just as valid a type as any other.

Answer (score 0):

no, because in a different call, the argument might be coming from wherever.  the compiler surely cannot chase your pointers *at runtime*.

edit: btw, this works for me, but requires -std=c++0x (I'm using gcc 4.4)

```
#include <iostream>

template <int n>
struct T
{
    T&
    operator=(double const cc[n])
    {
        c = cc;
        return *this;
    }
    const double
    operator[](int const &i)
    {
        return c[i];
    }
    double c[n];
};

template<int n>
double
f(T<n> & x)
{
    return x[n-1];
}

int
main()
{
    T<5> t5 = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    T<3> t3 = {100, 200, 300};
    std::cout << f(t5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << f(t3) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm specifically asking about the multi-dimensional case. There are additional things going on there that aren't present in the single dimension case. It seems easy enough to infer "int arr[N]" but "int arr[N][M]" is too difficult.

Answer (score -2):

This could help you with your larger problem (whatever that may be). This will allow you to query the size/type of the array at compilation.

```
template < typename T_, unsigned N_ >
class many {
public:
    typedef T_ T;
    enum { N = N_ };

    T array[N];
};
```

Justin

Comment: Eh? How does this help?