# How can you prevent decay in a function template taking T by value?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, function-templates

Please consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void f(T x) {
    std::cout << sizeof(T) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int array[27];
    f(array);
    f<decltype(array)>(array);
}
```

*Editor's Note:* the original code used `typeof(array)`, however that is a GCC extension.

This will print

```
8 (or 4)
108
```

In the first case, the array obviously decays to a pointer and T becomes `int*`. In the second case, T is forced to `int[27]`.
Is the order of decay/substitution implementation defined? Is there a more elegant way to force the type to `int[27]`? Besides using std::vector?

Comment: Where did you find a C++ compiler where `sizeof(int) == 1`? I get 108 for the second call.

Comment: Yes, of course gcc has already moved up to 4 byte ints ;-) I introduced a bug while generating a testcase.

Comment: I'm surprised the second call compiles. You can't pass arrays by value in C++. [edit: Ah, `T` has the array type, but `sizeof(x)` would still output 8 or 4. Never mind. :)]

Comment: Nice necro comment :-) Are you just browsing my old questions? :-) The second case is passing the array as reference, that's what I didn't recognize when I asked. See the accepted answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the reference type for the parameter

```
template<typename T> void f(const T& x) 
{
  std::cout << sizeof(T);
}
```

in which case the array type will not decay.

Similarly, you can also prevent decay in your original version of `f` if you explicitly specify the template agument `T` as a reference-to-array type

```
f<int (&)[27]>(array);
```

In your original code sample, forcing the argument `T` to have the array type (i.e. non-reference array type, by using `typeof` or by specifying the type explicitly), will not prevent array type decay. While `T` itself will stand for array type (as you observed), the parameter `x` will still be declared as a pointer and `sizeof x` will still evaluate to pointer size.

Comment: Yes, but I am using sizeof(T). Anyway, thanks for the fast answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour of this code is explained by C++14 [temp.deduct.call]:

> **Deducing template arguments from a function call**
>
> Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function template parameter type (call it `P`) with the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it `A`) as described below

and then below:

> If `P` is not a reference type:
>
> - If `A` is an array type, the pointer type produced by the array-to-pointer standard conversion (4.2) is used in place of `A` for type deduction;

For the call `f(array);`, we have `A` = `int[27]`. `A` is an array type. So the deduced type `T` is `int *`, according to this last bullet point.

We can see from the qualifier "If `P` is not a reference type" that this behaviour could perhaps be avoided by making `P` a reference type. For the code:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void f(T (&x)[N])
```

the symbol `P` means `T(&)[N]`, which is a reference type; and it turns out that there are no conversions applied here. `T` is deduced to `int`, with the type of `x` being `int(&)[N]`.

---

Note that this only applies to function templates where the type is deduced from the argument. The behaviour is covered by separate parts of the specification for explicitly-provided function template parameters, and class templates.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, you can work around that [using references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745942/c-template-parameter-in-array-dimension/1745963#1745963):

```
template<typename T>
void f(const T& x) {
    std::cout << sizeof(T);
}

char a[27];
f(a);
```

That prints `27`, as desired.

Comment: Probably should use a const-reference, since you're not modifying T.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use templates like the following:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
inline std::size_t number_of_elements(T (&ary)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

This little trick will cause compile errors if the function is used on a non-array type.