# Why does array type not decay to pointer for class templates?

Tags: c++, c++11

We know that [arrays decay to pointers in function templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863751/array-decay-to-pointers-in-templates) and to take an array type parameter we need to declare our function template with a reference-to-array:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t number_of_elements(T (&ary)[N]) {
  return N;
}
```

However, why do we not need to declare reference-to-array parameters in class templates? The code below shows this and compiles under C++11.

```
template<class T>
struct cls_number_of_elements {};

template<class T, std::size_t R>
struct cls_number_of_elements<T[R]> {
  static const int N = R;
};

char ary[] = "12345";
auto const N = cls_number_of_elements<decltype(ary)>::N;
char ar2[N];
```

Comment: I think it might be because `decltype(ary)` makes it an array type, whereas template deduction would decay it to a pointer.

Comment: Thanks @JamesRoot. What's confusing especially is that the decay happens for both `template<class T> void array_template(T t)` and `template<class T, std::size_t N> void array_template(T ary[N])` when the function is passed an array-type argument.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Both your code samples are fine and there isn't any contradiction between the two.  Can you perhaps show a piece of code that doesn't work but you think it should?

Comment: The question you linked is about function template deduction , whereas your second code sample is about class templates. Generally speaking, function templates and class templates have different rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "decay" you are talking about is something that happens *when deducing a function template parameter from an argument*.  I have posted a fuller explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33734010/1505939).

When you explicitly provide a value for a template parameter, there is no deduction step; the value you explicitly provided is exactly the value that the parameter takes.

With class templates, there is never parameter deduction; they must always have their parameters explicitly provided.

Illustrative examples:

```
template<typename T> void f(T t) {}
template<typename T> struct S { void f(T t) {} };

...

int x[27];
f(x);               // Type deduction: decay occurs, T = int *
f<int *>(x);        // No deduction. T = int *
f<int[27]>(x);      // No deduction. T = int[27]
S<int[27]>().f(x);  // No deduction. T = int[27]
```

In the latter two cases, *adjustment* still occurs. [temp.deduct]/3 explicitly restates this: when `T` is an array type, the *function parameter* `T t` means that `t` has a pointer type, in exactly the same fashion that:

```
void g(int t[27])
```

actually specifies that `t` has type `int *`.

Answer (score 2):

From the C++11 Standard:

> **7.1.6.2 Simple type specifiers**
>
> 4 The type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> — if `e` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* or an unparenthesized class member access (5.2.5), `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or if `e` names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
>
> — otherwise, if `e` is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
>
> — otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
>
> — otherwise, `decltype(e)` is the type of `e`.

Given

```
char ary[] = "12345";
```

`decltype(ary)` denotes the type of `ary` (an unparenthesized *id-expression*), which is `char[6]`.

A more user friendly description of `decltype` can be found at [http://en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).

Answer (score 0):

Well between the C and C++ standards and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1462103) it looks like the explanation is:

> #### 4.2 Array-to-pointer conversion
>
> 1. An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of `N` `T`” or “array of unknown bound of `T`” can be converted to an rvalue
>      of type “pointer to `T`.” The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

Looks like this conversion **does** happen for deduced template arguments in a function template

```
number_of_elements(ary)
```

but **not** for template arguments in class templates

```
cls_number_of_elements<char[5]>
```

and explicitly-typed function templates

```
number_of_elements<char[5]>(ary)
```

since those types are not deduced.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code I have a very short explanation which doesn't have anything to do with the differences between class and function templates:

For `number_of_elements` the "type" of the array is `T[N]`. Sample applies to `cls_number_of_elements`where the "type" is `T[R]`.
In both cases the `T` will become `char` while `N` resp. `R` becomes `6`.
The only reason why you need the `&` is because you cannot pass c arrays by value.
(see anser from @bku_drytt)

Comment: It's worth clarifying that you *can* pass `std::array` (or an array that is a member of any other type of object) by value.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated my answer to clarify that this can not be done for c arrays.