# C++ Template using typename and passing typedef to function

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, typename

I am using template in this manner.

```
#define MAX_CARS 999
typedef char plate[20];

template <typename T>
int insert_ord (T V[], int ll, int const LF, T e);
```

It works but when I pass a typedef as arguments it says: No matching function for call to "insert_ord".

This is the main.

```
int main (void)
{
    plate targhe[MAX_CARS];        
    int ll = 0;

    plate targa;
    cin >> targa;

    ll = insert_ord(targhe, ll, MAX_CARS, targa);

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See ["Array decay to pointers in templates"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863751/array-decay-to-pointers-in-templates). You should use reference in order to preserve type. Try `int insert_ord (T V[], int ll, int const LF, T &e)` where `e` is reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
int insert_ord (T V[], int ll, int const LF, T e);
```

The *function-template* above will not work for arguments of type:

```
(int[999][20], int, int, int[20])
```

The first parameter of your `insert_ord` function is a 2D array of `plate`, while the last is of type `plate` which is a 1D array. You should declare the *function-template* like:

```
template <typename T, int sizeOuter, int sizeInner>
int insert_ord (T (&v)[sizeInner][sizeOuter], int ll, int const LF, T (&e)[sizeOuter]);
```

See it [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7058620e3536b6c0)

---

However, a few nitpicks with your code. you don't need that `void` in `int main()`. And prefer `constexpr` over `#define` if possible. Most importantly, use [`std::array<T, N>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or consider wrapping your data structure in a `class` or `struct`