# Can I pass a built-in array to std::ostream_iterator without an array-to-pointer decay?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++20

I have overloaded `operator<<` to print a built-in array `const int (&arr)[N]`:

```cpp
template <size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const int (&arr)[N])
{
    os << "{ ";
    bool first{true};
    for (int i : arr)
    {
        os << (first ? "" : ", ") << i;
        first = false;
    }
    return os << " }";
}
```

I can use it to print a `const int (&)[5]` array to `std::cout`:

```cpp
    int arr[3][5] = {{3, 4, 6, 1, 1}, {6, 3, 4, 5, 1}, {6, 1, 2, 3, 3}};

    for (const auto& subarr : arr) { std::cout << subarr << "\n"; }

// Outputs:
//
//   { 3, 4, 6, 1, 1 }
//   { 6, 3, 4, 5, 1 }
//   { 6, 1, 2, 3, 3 }
```

However, when I try to print the same array via a `std::copy` to `std::ostream_iterator<const int (&)[5]>`, I just get the array address printed out:

```cpp
std::copy(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr),
        std::ostream_iterator<const int (&)[5]>{std::cout, "\n"});

// Outputs:
//
//   0x7ffec4f84db0
//   0x7ffec4f84dc4
//   0x7ffec4f84dd8
```

I suppose the array is decaying to a pointer at the `ostream_iterator` end. If so, is there a way to avoid that?

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/r4zj7nTWK) for a working version.

---

There are many questions in this site regarding array-to-pointer decay, but I haven't seen one that was helping with this case.

Actually, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1863767/260313) says:

> [...] you can also prevent decay in your original version of `f` if
> you explicitly specify the template agument `T` as a
> reference-to-array type
>
> `f<int (&)[27]>(array);`

But that doesn't seem to be happening when constructing the `ostream_iterator`.

Comment: There's always a danger of ADL interference when trying to provide the insertion `operator<<` of a built-in type.  (There's probably a rule against that.)  You can have an `struct Arr5 { int const (&arr)[5]; Arr5(int const (&a)[5]) : arr{a} {} };` helper class that has the `operator<<` behavior you want, and then call it via `ostream_iterator<Arr5>{cout, "\n"}`.

Comment: @Eljay Many thanks! Actually, that was also the solution proposed by Barry in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with array-to-pointer decay and everything to do with how name lookup works.

In this version:

```cpp
for (const auto& subarr : arr) { std::cout << subarr << "\n"; }
```

your `operator<<` is a candidate because regular unqualified lookup will find it.

But that's not what `ostream_iterator` does, its implementation internally will do something like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void whatever(std::ostream& os, T const& arg) {
    os << arg;
}
```

And that `os << arg` call is going to not find your `operator<<` candidate by unqualified lookup (it won't have been declared at the point of definition of the header) and it's not going to find your `operator<<` by argument-dependent lookup (since it's not in an associated namespace of either argument). Since your function isn't a candidate, instead the one selected is the pointer one - which is why it formats the way it does.

One (bad, don't do this) solution would be to put your `operator<<` overload inside of `namespace std`, which would cause argument-dependent lookup to be able to actually find it. But don't do this, since you're not allowed to add things to `namespace std` (and, generally speaking, shouldn't add your things to other people's namespaces).

So the better solution would be to instead create your own type that formats the way you want it to, since then you can just add an `operator<<` that properly associates with it - in a way that doesn't involve messing with `std`.

Comment: Thanks! I also thought about that. Then, I tried this other [little example](https://godbolt.org/z/cj96caz7z), doing the same but with a `struct A<N>`. I saw that my `operator<<` for `const A<N>&` was called, and I dismissed this option. What is my reasoning missing then?

Comment: @rturrado Was `A<N>` supposed to have an `int[N]` member, as opposed to an `int`?

Comment: No, my test simply tried to demonstrate that `std::ostream_iterator` could "see" my `operator<<` overload for `const A<N>&` . But I think I've understood the problem from what you've answered (although I fail to understand much of this ADL stuff): `ostream_iterator` will be able to look up and find `operator<<` for `const A<N>&` by searching where `A<N>` is declared; but it won't be able to find `operator<<` for `const int (&arr)[N]` by searching in the `std` namespace. Is it so?

Comment: @rturrado: `A`  is not a buit-in, ADL will look for operator in same samespace than `A`(, so global one).

Comment: @Jarod42 But, for `const int (&arr)[N]`, i.e. for built-in types, it won't look in the global one though, just in `std`.

Comment: @rturrado It won't look in `std` for built-in types -- for built-in types, only built-in operators are considered. `std` is looked into because it's an associated namespace of the *other* parameter - which is a `std::ostream`.

Comment: @Barry Ah, OK, thanks!